# How can I properly handle request errors with React front end?

Tags: reactjs

Currently I have my backend set up as such on the '/register' route:

```
registerRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  // Validate submitted registration form
  const { error } = registerValidation(req.body)
  if(error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)
  }
  try {
    // Check if email exists already
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    if(user) {
      return res.status(400).send('Email already exists')
    }
    // If not, begin registering user by hashing the password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    const newUser = new User({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword
    })
    const savedUser = await newUser.save()
    res.send(savedUser)

  } catch(error) {
    res.sendStatus(500)
  }
})
```

Using Postman I get the proper responses when I make correct/incorrect requests. But when I make requests on my frontend, if it is an incorrect request, e.g. not long enough password, missing a required field, then I just get a 400 response. How can I use the error response to, for example, display the error on-screen for the user to see?
This is my current onSubmit function for the form:

```
  const register = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios
      .post('/register', newUser)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Comment: In your catch block try logging `err.response` instead (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960)

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
 axios
  .post('/register', newUser)
    .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error.toJSON()); // or maybe exist .toText()
  });
```

(https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

also convert it on server side:

```
return res.status(400).send('Email already exists')
```

to

```
return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Email already exists' });
```